# not a single-group group function using select case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case-when

I am writing below query which divides the two select query and calculate the percentage. But i am getting an error as `not a single-group group function`

```
select CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE round((r.cnt / o.cnt)*100,3) END from 
    (Select count(*) as cnt from O2_CDR_HEADER WHERE STATUS NOT IN(0,1) and DATE_CREATED > (SYSDATE - 1)) r cross join
    (Select count(*) as cnt from O2_CDR_HEADER WHERE DATE_CREATED > (SYSDATE - 1)) o;
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff `r` is defined just before `cross join`.

Comment: It would be easier to tell that if you formatted your code in a readable manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use joins. If I were you, I'd do:

```
select case when count(*) = 0 then 0
            else round(100 * count(case when status not in (0, 1) then 1 end) / count(*), 3)
       end non_0_or_1_status_percentage
from   o2_cdr_header
where  date_created > sysdate - 1;
```

Here's a simple demo:

```
with t as (select 1 status from dual union all
           select 2 status from dual union all
           select 3 status from dual union all
           select 2 status from dual union all
           select 4 status from dual union all
           select 5 status from dual union all
           select 6 status from dual union all
           select 7 status from dual union all
           select 1 status from dual union all
           select 0 status from dual union all
           select 1 status from dual)
select case when count(*) = 0 then 0
            else round(100 * count(case when status not in (0, 1) then 1 end) / count(*), 3)
       end col1
from   t
where 1=0;

      COL1
----------
         0
```

---

And just in case you aren't sure that doing the filtering of the count in the case statement returns the same as when you filter in the where clause, here's a demo that proves it:

```
with t as (select 1 status from dual union all
           select 2 status from dual union all
           select 3 status from dual union all
           select 2 status from dual union all
           select 4 status from dual union all
           select 5 status from dual union all
           select 6 status from dual union all
           select 7 status from dual union all
           select 1 status from dual union all
           select 0 status from dual union all
           select 1 status from dual)
select 'using case statement' how_count_filtered,
       count(case when status not in (0, 1) then 1 end) cnt
from   t
union all
select 'using where clause' how_count_filtered,
       count(*) cnt
from   t
where  status not in (0, 1);

HOW_COUNT_FILTERED          CNT
-------------------- ----------
using case statement          7
using where clause            7
```

Comment: @Boniest even if i use joins or not it returns the same result for sure right ? There can be many ways to change the query logic ?

Comment: Yes, you'll get the same result, only - hopefully - faster.

Comment: I've just updated my answer to include a demo that doing the filtering of the rows to be counted in a case statement returns the same as if you'd filtered the rows in the where clause and then done a count(*).

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing an aggregate function (`COUNT(*)`) and an individual column expression (`r.cnt` and `o.cnt`) in the same SELECT query.  This is not valid SQL unless a GROUP BY clause is added for the relevant individual columns.

It would be easier to provide a valid alternative it you could clarify what you'd like this query to return (given a sample schema and set of data).  As a guess, I'd say you can simply substitute `COUNT(*)` with `o.cnt` to avoid the division by 0 issue.  If there's some other logic expected to be present here, you'd need to clarify what that is.

Comment: both of my inside select query are returning 0 till now. I dont understood where i have to use group by clause beacuse in case when statement itself i am getting interger number as return value right ? Its not returning number of rows or something

Comment: @Rahul - The engine can't guarantee that your subquery returns a scalar value, and it will expect you to refine your query to ensure that the ambiguous grouping problem does not occur.  As I stated above, there's no obvious reason you need to use the function `COUNT(*)` in the initial `SELECT` statement.  Just use `o.cnt` and be happy :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to get a percentage of status not in 0,1, or 0 if there is no results.

Maybe this is what you want for the first line?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (R.CNT = 0 AND O.CNT = 0) THEN 0 ELSE ROUND((R.CNT *100.0 / O.CNT),3) END
```

Comment: What if `R.CNT` is not 0, but `O.CNT` is? ;)

Comment: @PinnyM That can't happen, can it? The `r` set is a subset of the `o` set.The other way around would be possible, but in any case I think what the OP meant with `count(*) = 0` is that there is no result at all, and this would do that.

Comment: i think in this case i have to set it only for o.cnt to 0 because only for the alias o select condition if it returns 0 the nit will give an error divisible by 0 error

Comment: @jpw it won't unless running over a date edge between the subqueries :)  Granted that isn't practically going to happen, but checking for R.CNT doesn't really add anything here.  And none of these solutions check for 'any' rows in the source table like `COUNT(*)` does - but such a check wouldn't actually prevent division by 0.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a cross join. Select the counts and do a division later on.

```
select case when ocnt > 0 then round((rcnt / ocnt)*100,3)
       else 0 end
from
(
select 
CASE WHEN STATUS NOT IN(0,1) and DATE_CREATED > (SYSDATE - 1)
 THEN COUNT(*) END as rcnt,
CASE WHEN DATE_CREATED > (SYSDATE - 1)
 THEN COUNT(*) END as ocnt 
from O2_CDR_HEADER
group by status, date_created
) t
```

Comment: Perhaps not, but this isn't really addressing the question about why the error is happening. You've also added a GROUP BY for status and date_created which will result in multiple rows returned.  I don't think this is what the OP intended.

Answer (score 1):

Boneist's answer is fine, but I would write it as:

```
select coalesce(round(100 * avg(case when status not in (0, 1) then 1.0 else 0
                                end), 3), 0) as non_0_or_1_status_percentage
from   o2_cdr_header
where  date_created > sysdate - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer which works perfectly for me

```
select CASE WHEN (o.cnt = 0) THEN 0 ELSE round((r.cnt / o.cnt)*100,3) END from 
(Select count(*) as cnt from O2_CDR_HEADER WHERE STATUS NOT IN(0,1) and DATE_CREATED > (SYSDATE - 1)) r cross join
(Select count(*) as cnt from O2_CDR_HEADER WHERE DATE_CREATED > (SYSDATE - 1)) o
```